# Assign email message to google group categories

Tags: google-groups

Google Groups allows to organize posts by defining Categories (Settings -> Categories). This is an alternative to using Tags to classify group discussions (posts),

When posting to the group using the Web-interface, the author may select a category for the post.

Posts can be sent to the group members also by sending an email to the group email (e.g. my-group-name@googlegroups.com).

However, I could not find a way to assign such emails to the group's defined categories. How can this be done?